# Unable to start rabbitmq-server after enabling rabbitmq-management

Tags: magento, rabbitmq

I've installed Erlang and rabbitmq. After that started the service

`$ sudo systemctl start rabbitmq-server
 $ systemctl status rabbitmq-server
● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Fri 2018-10-19 10:50:10 CEST; 13s ago
 Main PID: 46976 (beam.smp)
   CGroup: /system.slice/rabbitmq-server.service
           ├─46976 /usr/lib64/erlang/erts-5.10.4/bin/beam.smp -W w -K true -A30 -P 1048576 -- -root /usr/li...
           ├─47073 inet_gethost 4
           └─47075 inet_gethost 4`

Then I enabled rabbitmq-management, and changed ownership

`$ sudo rabbitmq-plugins enable rabbitmq_management
The following plugins have been enabled:
  mochiweb
  webmachine
  rabbitmq_web_dispatch
  amqp_client
  rabbitmq_management_agent
  rabbitmq_management
Plugin configuration has changed. Restart RabbitMQ for changes to take effect.
 $ sudo chown -R rabbitmq:rabbitmq /var/lib/rabbitmq/`

Than created user, tag him and set permissions

`$ sudo rabbitmqctl add_user admin password!
Creating user "admin" ...
...done.
$ sudo rabbitmqctl set_user_tags admin administrator
Setting tags for user "admin" to [administrator] ...
...done.
$ sudo rabbitmqctl set_permissions -p / admin ".*" ".*" ".*"
Setting permissions for user "admin" in vhost "/" ...
...done.`

And bad happend there, I'm not able to restart the rabbitmq anyhow

`$ sudo systemctl status rabbitmq-server.service
● rabbitmq-server.service - RabbitMQ broker
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/rabbitmq-server.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2018-10-19 10:55:23 CEST; 17s ago
  Process: 59210 ExecStop=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmqctl stop (code=exited, status=2)
  Process: 59024 ExecStart=/usr/lib/rabbitmq/bin/rabbitmq-server (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 59024 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Oct 19 10:55:23 XEMDUB07APXD080 systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: main process exited, code=exited, ...LURE
Oct 19 10:55:23 XEMDUB07APXD080 rabbitmqctl[59210]: Stopping and halting node rabbit@XEMDUB07APXD080 ...
Oct 19 10:55:23 XEMDUB07APXD080 rabbitmqctl[59210]: Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@XEMDUB07APXD...own
Oct 19 10:55:23 XEMDUB07APXD080 rabbitmqctl[59210]: DIAGNOSTICS
Oct 19 10:55:23 XEMDUB07APXD080 rabbitmqctl[59210]: ===========
Oct 19 10:55:23 XEMDUB07APXD080 rabbitmqctl[59210]: attempted to contact: [rabbit@XEMDUB07APXD080]
Oct 19 10:55:23 XEMDUB07APXD080 systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service: control process exited, code=exite...us=2
Oct 19 10:55:23 XEMDUB07APXD080 systemd[1]: Failed to start RabbitMQ broker.
Oct 19 10:55:23 XEMDUB07APXD080 systemd[1]: Unit rabbitmq-server.service entered failed state.
Oct 19 10:55:23 XEMDUB07APXD080 systemd[1]: rabbitmq-server.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
lskdlskdlskd`

What should I do to get rabbitmq start again?
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I foud answer here: https://github.com/rabbitmq/chef-cookbook/issues/182

In logs file i found:

```
`=INFO REPORT==== 19-Oct-2018::12:19:04 ===
Error description:
   {error,
       {cannot_read_enabled_plugins_file,"/etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins",
           eacces}}
    Log files (may contain more information):
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@XEMDUB07APXD080.log
   /var/log/rabbitmq/rabbit@XEMDUB07APXD080-sasl.log
Stack trace:
    [{rabbit_plugins,read_enabled,1,
                    [{file,"src/rabbit_plugins.erl"},{line,80}]},
     {rabbit_plugins,prepare_plugins,3,
                    [{file,"src/rabbit_plugins.erl"},{line,109}]},
    {rabbit,'-boot/0-fun-1-',0,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,334}]},
    {rabbit,start_it,1,[{file,"src/rabbit.erl"},{line,358}]},
    {init,start_it,1,[]},
    {init,start_em,1,[]}]
 code here
`
```

All I had to do is to change permissions to /etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins by

`chmod 644 /etc/rabbitmq/enabled_plugins`

And it started now.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with windows. I didn't find a solution by googling.
{error,{cannot_read_enabled_plugins_file,"C:\RabbitMQ\ENABLE~1",eisdir}} 
I had set my HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH configured in environment variables as c: and \RabbitMQ. But rabbimq ignore these values.

I had a folder named "enabled_plugins" in C:\RabbitMQ folder. RabbitMQ is expecting a file in %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% folder.

Solution was to delete enabled_plugins folder at C:\RabbitMQ path and create the file named enabled_plugins in %HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH% folder.

Other steps involved:

1) Install erlang. check if environment variables point to correct erlang path
 In my case envName:ERLANG_HOME value: C:\Program Files\erl10.0.1

2) Install RabbitMQ windows installer

3) Configure fire wall(if necessary). see Advanced Firewall setting(see on left panel of Firewall settings) from Control Panel.

Add new rules based on below.

Rule Type   Port
Protocols and Ports TCP
Specified local ports   5672, 15672
Action  Allow the connection
Profile Domain, Private, Public
Name    RabbitMQ

Rule Type   Program
Program path    %ProgramFiles%\erl7.2.1\bin\erl.exe
Action  Allow the connection
Profile Domain, Private, Public
Name    Erlang

Rule Type   Program
Program path    %ProgramFiles%\erl10.0.1\erts-10.0.1\bin\erl.exe
Action  Allow the connection
Profile Domain, Private, Public
Name    Erlang RunTime

Rule Type   Program
Program path    %ProgramFiles%\erl10.0.1\erts-10.0.1\bin\epmd.exe
Action  Allow the connection
Profile Domain, Private, Public
Name    Erlang Port

4) Copy RabbitMQ folder from %APPDATA% to C: drive and delete from %APPDATA% folder
   (This can be done after signout and re-log-in).

5) Set environment variable (system variables) RABBITMQ_BASE = C:\RabbitMQ and RABBITMQ_MNESIA_BASE= C:\RabbitMQ\db, make sure db folder exist.

6) Run RabbitMQ command prompt (Run As Administrator) (or command prompt path C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.8\sbin)

7) SET HOMEDRIVE=C: SET HOMEPATH=\RabbitMQ from command prompt

8) rabbitmq-service.bat remove

9) rabbitmq-service.bat install

10) rabbitmq-service.bat start

11) rabbitmq-plugins.bat enable rabbitmq_management (if authentication didn't match check erlang cookie)

12) rabbitmqctl.bat status (to check status)

13) remove readonly attribute from C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile.erlang.cookie file.(right click properties)

14) Make sure cookies at C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile content is same as 
%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%.erlang.cookie

15)http://localhost:15672/#/, you should see the login screen.

16) login with guest/guest and create virual host and configure your bus(sender). Start your background service pointing to this virtual host.